# Indenting pseudocode

Tags: indentation, enumerate, algorithms, algorithmicx

I'm having trouble indenting a block of pseudocode within an enumeration. Or perhaps more specifically, the algorithm's pseudocode seems to ignore the enumerations indentation. I'm working with the **algorithmicx** and **algpseudocode** **packages**.

```
\begin{enumerate} 
\item Some text...   
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
    \State $a\gets b$
    \State $b\gets r$
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{enumerate}
```

How can I force the algorithm block to follow the same indentation as the enumeration block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting your algorithm inside an `algorithm` *floating* environment. And, floats are set (by default) to have full width (`\textwidth`). It seems like you wish to retain the "floating" structure (ruled) *without* the floating behaviour (since you're setting it in a list). Then you need to do two things:

1. Set the float inside a `minipage` of width `\linewidth` which adapts to the width of the line inside lists (see [Difference between `\textwidth`, `\linewidth` and `\hsize`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16942/5764)); and
2. Due to (1) above, you need to remove the floating behaviour and set it using the `[H]` float specifier (provided by [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) which is loaded by [`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm)).

Here's the end result in the form of a MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{algorithms,algorithmicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate} 
  \item Some text\ldots\par
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}

  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
          \State $a\gets b$
          \State $b\gets r$
          \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
        \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
      \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}

  Some more text\ldots
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked very well. Thank you for the thorough explanation.