# Automatic line-break in tabular

Tags: tables, line-breaking, tabularx

I'm making a tabular and I'd like to automatically do a like break rather than going beyond the page.

This is my tabular code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
Use Case Navn:          & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Opret Server} \\
Scenarie:               & \multicolumn{2}{l}{At oprette en server med bestemte regler som tillader folk at spille sammen. More Text more text More Text} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nag}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}
```

This is how it looks right now: [image]

Comment: some pointers in [Automatic line-breaks in tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137475/579).

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Since you've tagged the question `tabularx`, this is a solution with [`tabularx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) (no need for those `\multicolumn`s)

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
Use Case Navn:          & Opret Server \\
Scenarie:               & At oprette en server med bestemte regler som tillader folk at spille sammen. More Text more text More Text \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The column type `X` takes all the space left from other columns till `\textwidth` or whatever you specify in the first argument.

Comment: The reasoning behind using multicolumn is that I need the tabular to be 2 cells in the upper part of the tabular and 3 cells in the lower one. Apologies for not showing you this in the original post, but this is how the tabular looks like in Word (just started studying LaTeX at school), so we need to "transform" a word document to LaTeX. Anyway, here's the tabular in word: http://prntscr.com/33xuog

Comment: What should I use instead of `X` if I am using double column? @karlkoeller

Comment: How to make it ragged right instead of justified?

Answer (score 45):

One of the approaches is to use a `p` type column, `p{dimension}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} \hline
Use Case Navn:& \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Opret Server} \\ \hline\hline
Scenarie:& \multicolumn{2}{p{4cm}|}{\raggedright At oprette en server med bestemte regler som tillader folk at spille sammen. More Text more text More Text} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use `\multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}|}` with `1` instead of `2` columns. *Then we don't need 3 columns (`|l|l|l|`) for a 2 column table...*

Comment: Is it possible to make the text in the first column placed in the center of the cell?

Comment: @Ghrua `\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|}` should help with the horizontal centering. Try `multirow` package for vertical centering.  I've never needed an automatic way, I would probably check out the `tabu` package or I'd try the `tikz` package.