# Why is \rotate useless in deluxetable?

Tags: tables

The command `\rotate` is useless.

I searched the web and somebody said it is common and weird.

### How to rotate it then?

I download a 2028K configuration files herehttp://authortools.aas.org/aastex/downloads.html and the rotation problem is fixed.

**However I still do not know how to fix it if I use my original configuration file. Can you rotate the table using the tex code below?**

**And can you put the whole table in a single page?**

Test tex is as below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,preprint]{aastex}
\begin{document}
\rotate
\begin{deluxetable}{lllllllllllll}

\tabletypesize{\tiny}
\startdata
113b&2014-10-16:21.3&2014-10-17:20.6&2.76358799&11:07:53.107&+6:12:05.9&16.971279167&26.8683055556 &2014-10-17 13:21:00 &2014-10-17 19:26:00 &2014-10-17 21:21:00 &2014-10-18 03:25:00&ok\\`
\enddata

\end{deluxetable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The standard command for rotating text is `\rotatebox`

Comment: **Reviewers!** 27 minutes 4 votes? Really?

Comment: @percusse: I thought I made a comment that's it too early after 15 min. (2 close votes) already. Either it was removed or I accidentally forgot to add the comment after typing. You are right... it's too fast

Comment: @percusse: A good average, isn't it? @ questionhang: The question really needs more clarification: lot of things are said to be weird, but then turns out they are the simplest way to accomplish some task.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\rotate` is mentioned in some stuff about `deluxetable` e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183433/how-can-i-change-the-vertical-alignment-of-a-rotated-deluxe-table (which admittedly doesn't have a MWE so I've closed). Something to do with http://authortools.aas.org/aastex/faq.html, I think.

Comment: @JosephWright ah: `\newcommand\rotate{\@pt@rottrue}%`

Comment: Why the heck was this closed as unclear after I'd answered it? It's perfectly clear: `\rotate` does not work if it is used incorrectly, and works if it is used correctly. (The title could be worded better but the question itself is clear enough)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 16):

[image]

`\rotate` goes before the data but within the environment:

```
\documentclass{aastex}

\begin{document}

\begin{deluxetable}{ccc}
\startdata
11&22&33\\
aa&bb&cc
\enddata
\end{deluxetable}

\begin{deluxetable}{ccc}
\rotate
\startdata
11&22&33\\
aa&bb&cc
\enddata
\end{deluxetable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your way, but the result page is empty if I use my original configuration file. Does it work if you use more columns? The tex data above has 13 columns. Can you put the columns in a single page?

Comment: @questionhang I used the MWE you have now supplied and it rotates as expected 9althougth it is too wide to fit on the page)

Comment: You use a special configuration file as the 2028k file I mentioned above? The font size of the table could not be reduced any more?

Comment: @questionhang The table is simply too wide: you'll need to rework it. I've no idea what you mean about a 'special configuration file': David has used the `aastex` class which provides both `\rotate` and `deluxetable` as in your example in the question.

Comment: @questionhang your question says "why is \rotate useless" but your comments seem to imply that your question is really "why does \rotate only rotate the table and not change fonts, or re-arrange the columns so the table is not wider than the page" ?

Comment: @ David I can rotate the table only in the environment the 2028k file gives. I need to put many columns in one page, so I wonder whether the font could be reduced arbitrarily.

Comment: @questionhang I assume the question about _rotating_ is answered, if so you should accept or close this question. If you have a question about font sizes or table formatting ask a new question. But make sure the example _in the question_ shows the problem, I and many other people answering do not fetch files from offsite servers. You can use a font size like `\small` or use a column spec like `p{.5cm}` instead of `c` to allow line breaking or ....

Comment: @ I am sorry. I will close this topic soon. Could you please write a whole sentence about p{.5cm}? Thanks.

Comment: @questionhang http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166743/automatic-line-break-in-tabular

Comment: @ you mean `\multicolumn{2}{p{4cm}|}`? It has nothing to do with deluxetable,right？

Comment: @questionhang I mean use `p{1in}` instead of `c` in `\begin{deluxetable}{ccc}` (I assume `\multicolum` also works with deluxetable as a matter of fact, it is just a wrapper around a standard tabular environment as far as I can see, although I have never used it) (but this is off topic for this rotating question)