# How can I break lines automatically in tabular to fit to page width?

Tags: line-breaking, longtable, tabularx

I expect to break a long text automatically in tabular. After searching this site, there are several ways:

**(i). Use `p{dimension}` in `tabular`, answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166743/automatic-line-break-in-tabular)**

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} 
\hline
key & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}|}{A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

As you can see, we need to assign `dimension`, not automatic.

**(ii). Use the package `tabularx`, answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166743/automatic-line-break-in-tabular)**

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
\hline
key & A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

**(iii). Use the package `longtable`, answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918366/automated-line-breaks-in-latex-tables)**

```
\begin{longtable}{|l|p{4cm}|}
\hline
key & A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

Here is the result.

[image]

**(iv). Other solutions?**

Comment: `longtable` is irrelevant here, it's the `p{4cm}` column specification that enables line breaking (for all cells in that column), and that works with `tabular` and `tabularx` as well.

Comment: VTC: "What is best..."-style questions typically tend to request opinion-based answers. Moreover, this question is too broad as it stands.

Comment: The reason there are no line breaks in your `longtable` example is that you have specified three columns, and the third one is a `p` column, but in the table there are only two columns, so the very long text ends up in an `l` column where line breaking does not happen. Remove one `l|` in the column specification.

Comment: `p{...}` should work in any tabular - environment which is derived from `array`, as far as I know. In addition to  Torbjørn T.'s comment use `{|*{2}p{4cm}|}` if you really need the `|`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Did you mean `\begin{longtable}{|l|p{4cm}|}`? Yes, it works.

Comment: So there is no way of getting automatic line breaks in a column with dynamic width? I was kind of hoping that, with the hundreds of table-related packages around, I would not have to fiddle around with `cm` values manually and keep adjusting them every time the table content changes. What these comments suggest is that you can either have a flexibly sized column, or automatic line breaks, but not both; am I understanding this correctly?