# Text overflows tabular in minipage

Tags: formatting, minipage, fbox

I want to reproduce this output from the book [Parameterized Complexity Theory](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540299523) by Flum and Grohe:
[image]

I try using a minipage, and an fbox. However, the text overflows the box, and linebreaks do not work:

[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip,multicol,amsmath,amsfonts}

\newcommand{\defPP}[4] 
{
    \fbox
    {   
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

            #1

            \begin{tabular}{r l}


                \textit{Instance:}& #2\\    
                \textit{Parameter:}& #3\\
                \textit{Problem:}& #4   
            \end{tabular}

        \end{minipage}
    }

}

\begin{document}
    \defPP{\emph{p}-\textsc{Bounded-NTM-Halt}}{A deterministic TM $\mathbb{M}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in unary, $k \in mathbb{N}$}{$k$}{Decide whether $\mathbb{M}$ accepts the empty string at most in $n$ steps and using at most $k$ nondeterministic steps.}

    To show that $p$-\textsc{Bounded-NTM-Halt} $\in \text{W[P]}$, [...]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer you're looking for is to use a `p` type column as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166746/121944).

Thus, substitute something like `\begin{tabular}{r p{9cm}}` where you currently have `\begin{tabular}{r l}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more automated approach using `tcolorbox` for the box and `tabularx`'s flexible width `X` column for the second column.

The first box occupies the whole textwidth, while the contents in the second column are automatically wrapped to fit into the box depending on the width of the first column.

The second alternative only uses part of the textwidth (using the `width=` option and is horizontally centered using the `center` environment.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip,multicol,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\defPPone}[4] 
{
   \begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners, colframe=black, colback=white, boxrule=0.75pt]
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}r X@{}}
         \multicolumn{2}{p{\linewidth}}{#1}\\
         \textit{Instance:}& #2\\    
         \textit{Parameter:}& #3\\
         \textit{Problem:}& #4   
       \end{tabularx}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\newcommand{\defPPtwo}[4] 
{
   \begin{center}
   \begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners, colframe=black, colback=white, boxrule=0.75pt,width=0.75\textwidth]
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}r X@{}}
         \multicolumn{2}{p{\linewidth}}{#1}\\
         \textit{Instance:}& #2\\    
         \textit{Parameter:}& #3\\
         \textit{Problem:}& #4   
       \end{tabularx}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}


\defPPone{\emph{p}-\textsc{Bounded-NTM-Halt}}{A deterministic TM $\mathbb{M}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in unary, $k \in \mathbb{N}$}{$k$}{Decide whether $\mathbb{M}$ accepts the empty string at most in $n$ steps and using at most $k$ nondeterministic steps.}

To show that $p$-\textsc{Bounded-NTM-Halt} $\in \text{W[P]}$, [...]

\defPPtwo{\emph{p}-\textsc{Bounded-NTM-Halt}}{A deterministic TM $\mathbb{M}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in unary, $k \in \mathbb{N}$}{$k$}{Decide whether $\mathbb{M}$ accepts the empty string at most in $n$ steps and using at most $k$ nondeterministic steps.}

To show that $p$-\textsc{Bounded-NTM-Halt} $\in \text{W[P]}$, [...]

\end{document}
```

[image]