# tabularx automatic line break and aligned over several tables

Tags: tables, line-breaking, tabularx

I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137475/automatic-line-breaks-in-tables) a solution to the problem of having an automatic line break:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for this example
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\medskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}l@{\hspace{.5em}}X@{}}
    2009--present & very long text 1, very long text 2, very long text 3, very long text 4, very long text 5, very long text 6, very long text 7, very long text 8, very long text 9, very long text 10 \\
    2009          & Masters                                                                                                                                                                              \\
    2006          & Bachelors
\end{tabularx}

 \end{document}
```

Now I have two similar tables within the same page and would like to align them after the first column. How can this be achieved, i.e. how do I have to modify the above command?

Comment: don't use `tabularx` just use a standard `tabular` with `p{2cm}p{7cm}` or whatever widths you need, then naturally all tables using that preamble will align.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how can I use the automatic line break with tabular?

Comment: @user8 - The `p` column type gives you automatic line breaks as well. In fact, the `X` column type is based on the `p` column type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `p`-column type for the first column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for this example
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\medskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}p{2.5cm}@{\hspace{.5em}}X@{}}
    2009--present & very long text 1, very long text 2, very long text 3, very long text 
    4, very long text 5, very long text 6, very long text 7, very long text 8, very long 
    text 9, very long text 10 \lipsum[5]\\
    2009          &  Masters  \\
    2006          & Bachelors \lipsum[6]
\end{tabularx}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}p{2.5cm}@{\hspace{.5em}}X@{}}
    2009          &  Masters  \\
    2006          & Bachelors \lipsum[6]
\end{tabularx}  
\end{document}
```