# How to allow page break in listliketab (with description style)?

Tags: luatex, page-breaking, tabularx

I am getting struggled with missing page breaks in long texts in listliketab.

This is my mwe:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[
ngerman
]{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}
\geometry{a6paper,left=20mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\PersA}[1]{\textit{Person A:} & #1\\}
\newcommand{\PersB}[1]{\textit{Person B:} & \textbf{#1}\\}
\newcommand{\Block}[1]{
    \storestyleof{description}
    \begin{listliketab}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\itshape}l @{\hspace{.5em}} XR}
            #1
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{listliketab}\\
}

\begin{document}
    \Block{
        \PersA{\lipsum[5]}
        \PersB{\lipsum[5]}
        \PersA{\lipsum[5]}
    }
\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image: Output]

How can I allow page breaks?

Comment: you can't if you use tabularx internally. It would perhaps works with longtable, but why don't you use a normal list?

Comment: I just copied it from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137484/195470) because I needed tabbing and line breaks. But I am open to better solutions.

Comment: I switched now to xltabular. It allows better page breaks, but still lacks forced page breaks in paragraphs.

Comment: yes that is the draw back of tabulars. That's why I always would use a normal list if possible.