# Columns in sublists

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, columns

Long lists of short bullet points look better when put besides using multiple columns. With top-level itemizations, this works easily with the environment columns. But when I try to use it inside a sublist

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item a top item
      \begin{itemize}
        \begin{columns}
          \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \item a sub item
          \end{column}
          \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \item another sub item
          \end{column}
        \end{columns}
      \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: items too broad]

it results in too broad items. As the sub-items also have the same font size as the one above, seemingly the itemization depth does not propagate into the columns.

Putting further itemize-environments into the columns did not work either. The generated document does not change.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item a top item
      \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
            \item a sub item
          \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
            \item another sub item
          \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
      \end{columns}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I columnize subitems in a single-columned list?

Answer (score 1):

Situations like these remind you the difference between `\textwidth` and `\linewidth`. Use `\linewidth`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item a top item
      \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
          \begin{itemize}
            \item a sub item
          \end{itemize}
        \end{column}%
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
          \begin{itemize}
            \item another sub item
          \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
      \end{columns}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want further indentation reduce `.5\linewidth` to something like `.4\linewidth`.

Refer [egreg's answer for details on the diffrences between `\linewidth` and `\textwidth`.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16956/11232)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the common mistake. Longer lists still do not work as expected. But I opened [another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139322/) for this concern.