# Why are subitems in beamer columns spaced wider?

Tags: beamer, spacing, lists, itemize, columns

[image: sub items of unequal spacing]

As seen in the picture, the sub-sub-items within the column are vertically spaced significantly wider than their counterparts outside any column. As I replaced the bullet points with depth numbers for better recognition, it can be clearly seen that they are on the same level. Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{(1)}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{(2)}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{(3)}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item a top item
      \begin{itemize}
        \begin{columns}
          \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \item a sub item
              \begin{itemize}
                \item deep subbed item a
                \item deep subbed item b
                \item deep subbed item c
              \end{itemize}
            \item another sub item
          \end{column}
          \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \item another column
          \end{column}
        \end{columns}
      \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item items outside columns
      \begin{itemize}
        \item sub items outside columns
          \begin{itemize}
            \item deep subbed item d
            \item deep subbed item e
            \item deep subbed item f
          \end{itemize}
      \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What causes the spacing to be modified in the column environment and how can it be corrected?

Comment: This only happens because you have an `itemize` inside a `column` which is inside another `itemize`

Comment: Correct. But "deep subbed item a" is surrounded by exactly as much itemization environments as "deep subbed item d" is. so should they not also have the save spacing?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

A `column` is essentially a `minipage` and one of the things `minipage` do when they start is reset the list depth; they are really designed for the way you are trying to nest them.

In an ordinary document you can reset the list depth as follows simply by changing `\@listdepth` appropriately encapsulated in `\makeatletter / \makeatother`:

[image: Sample minipage output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item a top item
  \begin{itemize}
    \begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}
    \item a sub item
      \begin{itemize}
      \item deep subbed item a wrongly spaced
      \item deep subbed item b
      \item deep subbed item c
      \end{itemize}
    \item another sub item
    \end{minipage}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
\item a top item
  \begin{itemize}
    \begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}\makeatletter\@listdepth2\makeatother
    \item a sub item 
      \begin{itemize}
      \item deep subbed item a correctly space
      \item deep subbed item b
      \item deep subbed item c
      \end{itemize}
    \item another sub item
    \end{minipage}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
\item a top item
  \begin{itemize}
    \item a sub item 
      \begin{itemize}
      \item deep subbed item a no minipage
      \item deep subbed item b
      \item deep subbed item c
      \end{itemize}
    \item another sub item
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

In `beamer` you can't change catcodes in a `frame` without adding the `fragile` option.  Often that is not desirable, so it is better to define a new command to do the setting of `\@listdepth`:

[image: Sample beamer output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{(1)}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{(2)}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{(3)}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setlistdepth}[1]{\expandafter\@listdepth#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item a top item
      \begin{itemize}
        \begin{columns}
          \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \item a sub item\setlistdepth{2}
              \begin{itemize}
                \item deep subbed item a
                \item deep subbed item b
                \item deep subbed item c
              \end{itemize}
            \item another sub item
          \end{column}
          \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \item another column
          \end{column}
        \end{columns}
      \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item items outside columns
      \begin{itemize}
        \item sub items outside columns
          \begin{itemize}
            \item deep subbed item d
            \item deep subbed item e
            \item deep subbed item f
          \end{itemize}
      \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally `bemear` is giving you the expected labels because it keeps track of those with `\@itemdepth` and not `\@listdepth`.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a `column`, it is is aligned with the center of the page, not to the `itemize`.

You need change the column position and vspace manually.

I add a column to the left (and adjust the width) and modify the vspace:

[image: with new column and vspace]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{(1)}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{(2)}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{(3)}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  { %%% to vspace affect only inside this block
    \item a top item
      \begin{itemize}

      \vspace{-3pt}

      \setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subsubbody begin}{\vspace{-2pt}}
      \setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subsubbody end}{\vspace{-2pt}}

      \newlength{\wideitemsep}
      \setlength{\wideitemsep}{\itemsep}
      \addtolength{\wideitemsep}{-2pt}
      \let\olditem\item
      \renewcommand{\item}{\setlength{\itemsep}{\wideitemsep}\olditem}

      \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.083\linewidth}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.417\linewidth}
          \item a sub item
            \begin{itemize}
              \item deep subbed item a
              \item deep subbed item b
              \item deep subbed item c
            \end{itemize}
          \item another sub item
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
          \item another column
        \end{column}
      \end{columns}
    \end{itemize}
  }
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item items outside columns
      \begin{itemize}
        \item sub items outside columns
          \begin{itemize}
            \item deep subbed item d
            \item deep subbed item e
            \item deep subbed item f
          \end{itemize}
      \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, this makes it look better. But I am trying to adjust the _vertical_ spacing, meaning the space between "deep subbed item a" and "deep subbed item b" should be as wide as the space between "deep subbed item d" and "deep subbed item e".

Comment: The `column` resets some properties of `itemize`. You need adjust this properties. I add some code to adjust `vspace` into a block `{...}`