# Use a box to fill text to right margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins, boxes, minipage

I often use an `eqnarray` (I know it's better to use `align`, but let's not worry about that for this question unless it changes the answer) as a way to list a bunch of definitions or descriptions of symbols. Here's an example:

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
  f & \text{:} & \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}The objective function that we're trying to maximize.\end{minipage} \\
  h & \text{:} & \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}The concave heuristic function that we can use to approximate $f$.\end{minipage}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

This produces:
[image]

A common problem, however, is that if my descriptions are too long, they will bleed past the end of the page. I've discovered that `minipage` can help in these kinds of situations. I've tried something like this:

```
    \begin{eqnarray*}
      \sqrt{\sin{f-g}} & \text{:} & \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}This is the description of a function but unfortunately goes past the right margin over the edge of the page.\end{minipage}
    \end{eqnarray*}
```

However, this causes the content to bleed over past the right margin, as seen:

[image]

One hack to fix this is to manually figure out how 'long' this `minipage` block should be, and use that measurement instead of `\textwidth` in the above code block. This is inflexible and requires change whenever the lenght of my equations change. How do I use a box/environment/other solution to automatically begin a newline when the text hits the absolute right margin on the page? My desired output would look something like:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: A `tabularx` environment would work wonders here. Are you at all concerned with breaking such an environment across the page boundary?

Comment: There is no possibility of `f & \text{:} & \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}` fitting into `\textwidth` as the third column is already that wide, so it is overfull even if empty. You should use a list, eg `\begin{description}\item[$\sqrt{\sin f-g}$: ] This is....`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Werner! `tabularx` seems promising, however it seems to have the same problem: http://imgur.com/UhqQMBv. The code that produced that is below. (Sorry, I don't know how to put code blocks in comments!) Suggestions?

        `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rcl}  
          $f$ &:& The objective... \\  
          $h$ &:& The heuristic... \\  
          $\sqrt{\sin{f-g}}$ &:& This is the description of a function but unfortunately goes past the right margin over the edge of the page.  
        \end{tabularx}`

Comment: Using `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rcX}...\end{tabularx}` seems to have accomplished what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following option uses [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to set the list/descriptions, and is therefore not breakable across the page boundary:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\newenvironment{mylist}
  {\par\centering\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}%
   \tabularx{\linewidth}{@{}l@{~:~}X@{}}}
  {\endtabularx
   \par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{mylist}
  $f$ & The objective function that we're trying to maximize. \\
  $h$ & The concave heuristic function that we can use to approximate~$f$\kern-.2em. \\
  $g$ & \lipsum*[2]
\end{mylist}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{mylist}
  $f$ & The objective function that we're trying to maximize. \\
  $h$ & The concave heuristic function that we can use to approximate~$f$\kern-.2em.
\end{mylist}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

You have to use an `X`-column in order to benefit from `tabularx`'s automatic resizing of columns. I've also used `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`, since the former is more appropriate if you're inside other list-like environments (where `\textwidth` might be too wide). As reference, see [Difference between `\textwidth`, `\linewidth` and `\hsize`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16942/5764).

For ease-of-use, I've only used two columns, with the middle-column *always* being a colon (`~:~`). It just promotes consistency to have a general setup, rather than duplicating the output for no apparent reason.

Note that your `mylist` environment will *always* have width `\linewidth`, even though the descriptions might be very short.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you very much! One last question, it seems that putting a `tabularx` environment inside of a `center` environment doesn't center the list/descriptions.  How would you recommend accomplishing this? (Of course, this is only relevant if the width of the longest row on the table is less than the linewidth.)

Comment: @MichaelTingley: Yes, in those instances, if you wish to have things centered, a different approach would have to be taken (possibly a 2-stage process: measure first, then set). `tabularx` requires a length according to which it measures and sets the `X`-columns. So, even if your contents is not as wide as `\linewidth`, it will be made to fit `\linewidth`. One could manage the two-stage process, but I'll have to do that later...