# How to set a box to a rubber length width

Tags: boxes, titlesec, lengths

## Problem

I'm trying to create fancy section heading using `titlesec`. I need to put the section name into a `\parbox` to have line breaks. I want the `parbox` to extend to the far right margin, but I don't know how to achieve this.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
%% Section
\titleformat{\section}[block]%
  {\normalfont\sffamily}%
  {\colorbox{black}{\parbox[c][17pt][c]{30pt}{%
      \hfil\color{white}\Large\thesection\hfil}}}%
  {0.15cm}%
  {%
   \raisebox{-3pt}{\parbox{10.5cm}{\hspace*{0.7pt}\color{black}\Large\sffamily#1\\[-3.5pt]%
   \color{black}\footnotesize\textbf\dotfill}}%
  }
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.3ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\section{Ridiculously overly extermely long section title, that definitely spans several lines.}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: You can try `\textwidth` or `\linewdith`.

Comment: ... or `\hsize` ([link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `\linewidth-30pt-1.5mm-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule` as your `\parbox` width. This removes the width of the numbered box (`30pt`), the `\colorbox` boundaries which is related to a `\framebox` (`2\fboxrule` and `2\fboxsep`) as well as the `0.15cm` gap between the box and the title from the `\parbox` width measurement:

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
%% Section
\titleformat{\section}[block]%
  {\normalfont\sffamily}%
  {\colorbox{black}{\parbox[c][17pt][c]{30pt}{%
      \hfil\color{white}\Large\thesection\hfil}}}%
  {0.15cm}%
  {%
   \raisebox{-3pt}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-30pt-1.5mm-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}{\raggedright\color{black}\Large\sffamily#1\\[-3.5pt]%
   \color{black}\footnotesize\textbf\dotfill}}%
  }
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.3ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\section{Ridiculously overly extermely long section title, that definitely spans several lines.}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but now I get an `Overfull \hbox (6.0pt too wide)...` and the title sticks out to the right.

Comment: You'll notice that I added `\raggedright` to the title so that it is not justified (removing the bizarre `\hspace*{0.7pt}`). I don't receive any overfull `\hbox`es (using [ShareLaTeX](http://www.sharelatex.com).

Comment: the heading would look a bit better if the lines weren't so far apart, and the box for the "reversed" number were somewhat taller, maybe spanning from the cap height of the top line to the baseline of the second.  (although that might make it look overly tall for a one-line header.  experiments with multiple lines in the header would be helpful.)

Comment: I got it: `\colorbox` is also an `\fbox`, so the correct width of the `\parbox` is `\dimexpr\linewidth-30pt-1.5mm-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep`.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Yes... sorry, I'll update my answer.