# The counterpart of "adjustwidth" as "adjustheight"

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, margins, document-classes

Is there a counterpart/similar function like "adjustwidth" to width, as the  "adjustheight" to height?

What I hope to see is something like shifting a whole table upward above the top margin, since the table is too "tall," we need to break the top margin locally on a page, so it can be fitted into the whole page without hitting the bottom.

```
\usepackage{changepage}    
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
      % <stuff>
    \end{adjustwidth}
```

e.g. see [changepage package's \adjustwidth environment adjusts only left margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149418/41144)

Thanks for the help! Happy Thanksgiving.

Comment: In the context of what you're asking, you can create space above an object by using a negative `\vspace`. It would be helpful if you could provide a complete example of the issue you're dealing with.

Comment: `\vspace*{-1cm}` (btw, a bad approach to fit large tables, IMHO).

Comment: But it looks that "\vspace*{-..cm}" only shifts the "\caption{}" part upward, it does not shift the contents of the Table upward. Thank you! Happy Thanksgiving.