# In nested tables, how can I make an inner table stretch to fit its column?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to design a layout that has tables nested within tables, and I'm having trouble getting things to line up.  The question is quite similar to [How to make width of an inner table use full column width of an outer table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151246/how-to-make-width-of-an-inner-table-use-full-column-width-of-an-outer-table) except that I have no `tabularx` involved---I am looking to get the table itself to stretch.
I imagine that a solution will have two components:

- Some stretchiness to `\tabcolsep`
- Some way of telling the outer table not to fill on the left and right sides

I have not been able to figure out how to achieve such an effect.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  A relatively wide line& Thin \\
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
    \hline
    A&B\\
    \hline
    C&D\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}&
  Thicker\\
The ABCD table should stretch to fit&Thickest\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The resulting table looks like

[image: MWE output]

but what I want is for the ABCD table to stretch the full width of its column (even though that would look awful in this case).

What I am actually trying to accomplish can be illustrated by considering the misalignments in the following non-minimal example:

[image: the actual problem I am trying to solve]

Two of the outcomes I would like are

- Section **E** stretches automatically to become the same width as section **D**
- Section **G** stretches automatically to become the same width as what's above it

Does anyone have ideas about how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

If you want stretching, you can't use a tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\columnA}
\newlength{\columnB}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\begin{document}

\settowidth{\columnA}{The ABCD table should stretch to fit}
\settowidth{\columnB}{Thickest}

\savebox{\tempbox}{%
\parbox[t]{\columnA}{\centering
A relatively wide line\\
\rule[1.5ex]{\columnA}{.5pt}\vspace{-1.5ex}
A \hfil B\\
\rule[1.5ex]{\columnA}{.5pt}\vspace{-1.5ex}
C \hfil D\\
\rule[1.5ex]{\columnA}{.5pt}\vspace{-1.5ex}
The ABCD table should stretch to fit}%
}%
\usebox{\tempbox}\hspace{\columnsep}%
\parbox[t][\dimexpr \ht\tempbox + \dp\tempbox][s]{\columnB}{\centering
Thin\vfill
Thicker\vfill
Thickest}

\end{document}
```

[image: table from scratch]

Comment: Too depressing. There must be a way to do it. `\settowidth` is not a bad trick, though.