# Can I get the effect of \halign to \hsize using a LaTeX tabular environment?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'd like to get the effect of doing `\halign to \hsize ...` while retaining all the convenience of LaTeX's `tabular` environment.  The particular problem I am trying to solve is to use `\tabskip` to set a bunch of (nested) tables to the same width in a column type of `p{`*width*`}`.  But if possible, I would like to set the inner table using `\begin{tabular}` and all its conveniences, rather than have to go for the raw `\halign`.

Possible?

(Related question: [In nested tables, how can I make an inner table stretch to fit its column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247705/in-nested-tables-how-can-i-make-an-inner-table-stretch-to-fit-its-column))

Comment: `\begin{tabular*}{\hsize}` is exactly that (and `\extracolsep` to set `\tabskip`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\begin{tabular*}{\hsize}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cc@{}}
```

should do what you need.