# Subfigures, long caption side by side

Tags: subfloats

Hello I have really big problems with positioning my sub figures. I have long caption text and I think that is the reason why they don't fit side by side. What can I do for solving this problem. [t] didn't work.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=12cm]{FIGURE1}
        \caption{Really long text over 2 lines}
        \label{fig:bestC1Sitting}
    \end{subfigure}% 

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=12cm]{FIGURE2}
        \caption{Really long text over 2 lines}
        \label{fig:bestC1Standing}
    \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}
```

I also don't get what's the point of \textwidth or linewidth? Are this relative positions?  I would be really glad if somebody can help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `\includegraphics[width=12cm]{FIGURE2}` where as your `0.5 text width` may not be 12cm. You should be using `width=\linewidth` You can use `width=\textwidth` also as `subfigure` is actually a `minipage` and  `\textwidth` refers to the width of text *inside* `minipage`. And don't leave a blank line in between subfigures as it would indicate a paragraph break. With this, we have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines}
        \label{fig:bestC1Sitting}
    \end{subfigure}%
    %%%                                             Don't leave blank line
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines}
        \label{fig:bestC1Standing}
    \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Looking UGLY isn't it?. We need some space in between. So change `\begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}` to `\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}` with a `\hfill` in between the subfigures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines}
        \label{fig:bestC1Sitting}
    \end{subfigure}%
    %%                          %   Don't leave blank line
    \hfill                      %%  <--- here
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines Really long text over 2 lines}
        \label{fig:bestC1Standing}
    \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> I also don't get what's the point of \textwidth or linewidth? Are this relative positions?

`\textwidth` is generally the global width of the text area. The parameter `\linewidth` contains the line length inside a list (or derived) environment and it may change in a nested list (while `\hsize`, `\textwidth` and `\columnwidth` don't change).

See [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16956/11232) from which I borrowed above lines. Hope it will be clear.

Comment: Can you adjust the width of the `\hfill`?

Comment: This causes all figures in my document to end up on a seperate page at the end of my document.