# Can't place figures side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, ieeeconf

I'm trying to place two TiKz pictures side by side in a two-column document (IEEEtrans style). I've looked at various solutions, but each one that claims to place figures side by side only manages to place the plots one above the other:

[image]

Currently I'm trying to use the `subfigure` environment:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf} 

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                           
\overrideIEEEmargins 


\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\newcommand{\tsc}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols}

\pgfplotsset{
tick label style={font=\tiny}, %axis numbers font size
label style={font=\small}, %axis labels font size
legend style={font=\tiny}
}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        %\input{figs/roc_curve.tikz}
        \resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\input{figs/roc.tikz}}  
        \caption{Caption A}
        \label{fig:A}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        %\input{figs/roc_curve.tikz}
        \resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\input{figs/roc.tikz}}  
        \caption{Caption B}
        \label{fig:B}
    \end{subfigure}    
    \caption{ROC curve of failure detection;}
    \label{fig:roc_curve}
\end{figure}

(...)

\end{document}
```

What exactly is forcing the plots to become only vertically aligned?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use `\linewidth` or `\columnwidth` instead of `\textwidth` in

```
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
```

in both places. `\textwidth` is the width of entire text including both columns. For details on `\linewidth` and `\textwidth` please refer [to this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16956/11232).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10 pt,conference]{ieeeconf}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}        %% or \columnwidth
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Caption A}
        \label{fig:A}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}        %% or \columnwidth
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Caption B}
        \label{fig:B}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{ROC curve of failure detection;}
    \label{fig:roc_curve}
\end{figure}

(...)

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have used `[b]` for both the `subfigure`s to align them properly.

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks! Courtesy `latexindent.pl` ;)

Comment: sweet :) you're one of the number one users! belated congratulations on topping 50K- I see a gold `tikz` badge will be yours soon, too :)

Comment: @cmhughes You are very kind. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to place two figures side by side over one column, Harish's solution is what you need. But if you want to place both figures over both columns, you have to use a `figure*` environment. When you use a `twocolumn` document, `figure` and `table` environments are as wide as a column, while `figure*` and `table*` use both columns.

Next example shows this differences. First one is taken from Harish's answer and the second one uses `figure*`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10 pt,conference]{ieeeconf}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}        %% or \columnwidth
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Caption A}
        \label{fig:A}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}        %% or \columnwidth
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Caption B}
        \label{fig:B}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{ROC curve of failure detection;}
    \label{fig:roc_curve}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}        %% or \columnwidth
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Caption A}
        \label{fig:A}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}        %% or \columnwidth
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Caption B}
        \label{fig:B}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{ROC curve of failure detection;}
    \label{fig:roc_curve}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]