# Horizontally center DFA

Tags: horizontal-alignment, automata

How can I horizontally center the following tikzpicture (which includes a DFA) on the whole page without changing the distance between the nodes?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{semantic}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,arrows,topaths}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}

\begin{document}
\section{LR(1) Grammars}
\begin{enumerate}

\item \leavevmode\vadjust{\vspace{\baselineskip}}\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
       \node[state,rectangle,initial,initial where=above] (0) {
            0
            $
            \begin{array}{l c r | r}
              {[} S  & -> & \cdot aA & \$ {]}\\
              {[} S' & -> & \cdot S  & \$ {]}\\
              {[} S  & -> & \cdot e  & \$ {]}
            \end{array}
            $
       };
       \node[state,rectangle,accepting] (1) [left=5cm of 0] {
            1
            $
            \begin{array}{l c r | r}
              {[}S' & -> & S \cdot & \$ {]}
            \end{array}
            $
       };
       \node[state,rectangle,accepting] (3) [right=8cm of 0] {
            3
            $
            \begin{array}{l c r | r}
              {[} S & -> & e \cdot & \$ {]}
            \end{array}
            $
       };
        \path[->]
        (0) edge  node {S} (1)
              edge  node {e} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The natural thing to do would be to use `\begin{center}`...`\end{center}`, but you [have to use a trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203397/centering-not-working-in-latex#comment667756_203973) for content larger than the current textwidth: wrap it in `\makebox[0pt]{`...`}`, to trick LaTeX into centering it.

```
\item \leavevmode\vadjust{\vspace{\baselineskip}}\newline
\begin{center}
\makebox[0pt]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
         \node[state,rectangle,initial,initial where=above] (0) {

  % ... rest of automaton ...

  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}
\end{enumerate}
```

And indeed:

[image]