# How to use the package cutout in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I am making presentations using `beamer`, I included the package `\usepackage{cutwin}`, but what does the parameters specify in `\begin{cutout}{1}{2pt}{3\linewidth}{4}`?

I want to make the text left of a figure but I got a mess as shown in the following.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref,ru,url}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf} % insert .eps figure
\usepackage{ragged2e} % justify text
\justifying % justify text
\tolerance=1 % disable hyphen at row end
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen % |
\hyphenpenalty=10000 % |
\hbadness=10000 % |
\let\olditem=\item % justify in \item 
\renewcommand{\item}{\olditem \justifying} %|
\usepackage{cutwin} % wrap figure
...
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example 2}
\begin{block}{Calculations and Plots}
Plot $\sin(2x)$, $\sin(x^2)$ and $\sin^2(x)$ when $0\leqslant x\leqslant 6$.
\end{block}

\opencutright
\vfill
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{%
\includegraphics[angle=0,width=1.6in]{eg2.eps}
}

\begin{cutout}{0}{0.7\linewidth}{0pt}{4}
\vspace{.5in}
$\color{blue}{>> x=linspace(0,6,100);}$\\
$\color{blue}{>> y1=sin(2*x);}$\\
$\color{blue}{>> y2=sin(x.^{\wedge} 2);}$\\
$\color{blue}{>> y3=(sin(x)).^{\wedge} 2;}$\\
$\color{blue}{>> plot(x,y1,x, y2,x, y3)}$\\

\end{cutout}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use simply the native `columns` environment instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example 2}
\begin{block}{Calculations and Plots}
Plot $\sin(2x)$, $\sin(x^2)$ and $\sin^2(x)$ when $0\leqslant x\leqslant 6$.
\end{block}

\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\linewidth}
$\color{blue}{>> x=linspace(0,6,100);}$\\
$\color{blue}{>> y1=\sin(2*x);}$\\
$\color{blue}{>> y2=\sin(x.^{\wedge} 2);}$\\
$\color{blue}{>> y3=(\sin(x)).^{\wedge} 2;}$\\
$\color{blue}{>> plot(x,y1,x, y2,x, y3)}$\\
\column{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[angle=0,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

### Remarks

- I suppressed parts of the code in the question that were not essential to the issue discussed here.
- `beamer` already loads `graphicx` and `hyperref`, so there's no need to load them in your document.
- If the text on the left is code, you could be interested in using the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package, for example which offers many features to help you typeset code.

Comment: Thanks! What does `\column{0.5\linewidth}` mean? I am guessing this column is set to locate at 50% of linewidth? BTW, what is linewidth in presentation? I usually use textwidth... @Gonzalo Medina

Comment: @ChiZhang You're welcome. Indeed, `\column{.5\linewidth}` declares a column of width `.5\linewidth`. \linewidth and \textwidth are equal in this particular context, but they might be differen; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16942/3954

Answer (score 4):

Or use the naive `minipage` approach.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example 2}
\begin{block}{Calculations and Plots}
Plot $\sin(2x)$, $\sin(x^2)$ and $\sin^2(x)$ when $0\leqslant x\leqslant 6$.
\end{block}   

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
$\color{blue}{>> x=linspace(0,6,100);}$\\
$\color{blue}{>> y1=\sin(2*x);}$\\
$\color{blue}{>> y2=\sin(x.^{\wedge} 2);}$\\
$\color{blue}{>> y3=(\sin(x)).^{\wedge} 2;}$\\
$\color{blue}{>> plot(x,y1,x, y2,x, y3)}$\\
\end{minipage}%   <-- this % is needed
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

[image]