# Maximum figure width when using bmcart class

Tags: floats, scaling

I am writing a paper for a journal and have to use the `bmcart` class of the BioMed Central template found [here](http://www.biomedcentral.com/authors/tex) ([direct link to ZIP file](http://media.biomedcentral.com/content/production/bmc_article-tex.zip)). I am using it with two columns:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{bmcart}
```

The `bmcart` class encloses every figure and its caption in a box. When I enable graphics in the template file:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\def\includegraphic{}
%\def\includegraphics{}
```

and insert a plot **without scaling**:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \includegraphics{myplot}
  \caption{\csentence{Sample figure title.}
      Figure legend text.}
      \end{figure}
```

then the plot overflows the box to the right. The width of my plot is `235 pt`, the width I got using `\showthe\columnwidth` in a `figure` environment.

My question is: what is the optimal width for plots that I want to include so that when I do `\includegraphics{myplot}` there is no scaling and the plot fits perfectly inside the box drawn around it?

I would be really grateful if you could point out how to determine the optimal width in this case, but also in general, if possible.

**Edit:** thanks to @[Fran](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11604/fran) for pointing out [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize) about the difference between `\hsize`, `\columnwidth`, `\linewidth` and other dimensions.

Comment: for me it is not clear what you want but can you try \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{myplot}?

Comment: I would try `\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{myplot}`.

Comment: @Mico, in the case of ``bmcart``, ``\columnwidth`` overflows the box boundaries to the right. I wrote that in my post but made a typo so it wasn't clear, now I fixed it.

Comment: @touhami, my goal was **not to scale** the plot using, i.e., the ``width`` parameter. However, your comment has lead me to a solution. If I make my plots as wide as ``\hsize`` then they fit perfectly without scaling! Thank you, please write this as an answer and I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @nedim there is no need to be answer. You're welcome.

Comment: @touhami, if you have time, it would be best that you answer so that other people with the same problem can find your solution more easily. In case you don't have time, I would write a short answer for that reason.

Comment: @nedim If so please do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `\hsize` returned the optimal width of the figure. `\showthe\hsize` returned `222.5 pt`. When I made a `222.5 pt` plot and included it in the paper using `\includegraphics{myplot}`, it fit perfectly without resizing.

In most cases though, `\hsize` should be avoided. I thank @[egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) for his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237900/maximum-figure-width-when-using-bmcart-class/237917#comment565235_237917) that clarifies why.

I thank @[touhami](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/71471/touhami) for his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237900/maximum-figure-width-when-using-bmcart-class?noredirect=1#comment564402_237900) that lead me to the solution.

Comment: I think that `\linewidth` is safer in general (see [this famous question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize)). BTW, why change  the original image size instead of using `[width=\linewidth]`? You can lost some image resolution in the original source and overall ...It's a lot of work!

Comment: @Fran, thanks for the link, I added it to my question. I changed the image size because I generate the images from a script and width is a parameter so it's not a lot of work. The reason I avoid scaling is that in that case all font sizes in the image correspond 1:1 to the rest of the document, so if the document is using a specific font in a certain size, I can make sure that the included image has exactly the same settings. It adds to the visual appeal.

Comment: Avoid using `\hsize`.

Comment: @egreg, what is the reason for avoiding ``\hsize``? I am not very experienced with LaTeX.

Comment: @nedim Because `\hsize` is an internal parameter and you're not guaranteed that its current value is the line width that will be used for typesetting the paragraph. On the other hand, in lists you can rely on `\linewidth`, while outside of lists `\columnwidth` is the parameter to be used.

Comment: @egreg, thank you, I added this information to the answer.