# What is the default length of \hrule?

Tags: packages, margins, rules, lengths

When used without parameters, what varfiable controls the length of `\hrule`?

I.e., how can I change the *default* length of `\hrule`, other than adding parameters to each instance -- say, to affect existing commands defined in a package?

The following example shows that it does not seem to depend on margins or `\textwidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
\hrule
a\dotfill\verb|\textwith|=\the\textwidth
\begin{adjustwidth}{0in}{2in}
\addtolength\textwidth{-5cm}
a\dotfill\verb|\textwith|=\the\textwidth
\hrule
a\dotfill\verb|\textwith|=\the\textwidth
\dotfill
\end{adjustwidth}
a\dotfill\verb|\textwith|=\the\textwidth
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize

Comment: @touhami I tried to change `\textwidth`, `\linewidth`, and `\hsize`, but it has no effect on `\hrule`.

Comment: You can't: `\hrule` (as explained by Mico) has ***no*** default width; either you explicitly specify a width, or the one of the enclosing vertical box will be used.

Comment: @egreg In fact yours is the best answer: "`\hrule` has no default width".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a rule in *vertical* mode. You need a vbox if you want to change the width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

a\dotfill\verb|\textwith|=\the\textwidth
\hrule

\vspace{5mm}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
foo\hrule
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So there is no simple variable to treak, other than enclose the whole thing in `minipage`?

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh - See my answer for a method that sets the width directly.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh: Instead of `\hrule` use `\rule{<width>}{<height>}` or define the width of the `\hrule`. `\rule` works in horizontal mode like `\hrulefill`.

Answer (score 13):

`\hrule` is a TeX primitive. On p. 221 of the TeXbook, Knuth says that the width of the rule that is created by `\hrule`

> depends on the context; the rule will extend to the boundary of the smallest box or alignment that encloses it.

Quite frequently, this means that the width of the rule will equal `\textwidth`, since the box that encases the rule encases the entire textblock.

If you need to set the width explicitly (and want to stick with the `\hrule` syntax), you should write, say,

```
\hrule width0.5\textwidth
```

or

```
\hrule width5cm
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can set it on each instance. The question is how can I change the default for some block. It seems that `minipage` is an option, but is there any simple variable to tweak, like `{\somelength=1cm lots of code with many \hrule}`?

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh you can try something like `\newlength{\rulewidth}
\newcommand\mtrule{\hrule width \rulewidth}
\newcommand\somelength[1]{\setlength{\rulewidth}{#1}}
{\somelength{1cm} lots of code with many \mtrule}`