# Center Image to Page Inside Enumerate

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, margins, enumerate

I am trying to post an image inside an enumerated list but the left margin it starts with is the indented margin from enumerate.  Is there any way to ignore that without having to break the enumerate?  Here is what I have:

```
% Part (a)
\item A single plot showing the temporal change of the "High" and "Low" attributes\\\\
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{HW2_2a.png}
```

and the output is:

[image]

As you can see its being pushed to far to the right and just looks weird

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 2):

You have two possibilities:

- discontinue itemize for inserting image
- define new environment, which will do this just for image.

In second case try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{restoretext}%
    {\@parboxrestore%
     \begin{adjustwidth}{}{\leftmargin}%
    }{\end{adjustwidth}
     }
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{itemize}
\item   \lipsum[2]
    \begin{restoretext}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image}
    \end{restoretext}
\item   \lipsum[2]
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `\linewidth` instead of `\textwdith` which has the advantage that it is clear that the image is part of the current item.

[image]

### References:

- [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{itemize}
    \item   \lipsum[2]

    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{../images/EiffelWide}
    
    \item   \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```