# Line spanning across page inside list

Tags: lists, enumerate

I need a horizontal line to span across the page, up to the right margin (where the text would end). This works:

```
\rule{\hsize}{0.4pt}
```

But, when inside a list, the line goes over the margin because it is indented, and \hsize of course doesn't check for indentation.

How can I make the line's length account for the list's indentation?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Some section}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Some text \\ \rule{\hsize}{0.4pt}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: output]

As you can see, the line goes over the right margin. (compare to left and top margins)

Comment: Please provide a complete, compilable example.

Comment: @cfr added example

Comment: You don't need a `\documentclass` to compile it? Or a `document` environment? Amazing. I do.

Comment: @cfr thats implied

Comment: No. A minimal working example (MWE) is complete. It should be such that it can be copy-paste-compiled either successfully or to reproduce the error. If people have to add stuff which you merely 'implied', it is not complete. And it is also ambiguous. The class you use frequently matters. Lots.

Comment: I've completed your example by way of illustration. Hope this helps you to provide one next time you need to ask a question. Please read [this thread](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?s=3|0.6302) for a complete explanation of what's required.

Comment: \linewidth works in this case.   Which brings up the question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize?s=1|0.9464

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\begin{itemize}
  \item first \hrulefill
  \item second
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: minimal output]