# Why the sum of columns width in a table is less than 1?

Tags: tables

Tell me please, why the sum of columns width in a table is less than 1?
That is my code:

```
\begin{tabular}
{p{0.15\textwidth}p{0.12\textwidth}p{0.17\textwidth}p{0.17\textwidth}p{0.27\textwidth}}
...
\end{tabular}
```

0.15 + 0.12 + 0.17 + 0.17 + 0.27 = 0.88
Only at that case I have a textwidth table. If the sum  is equal one I have a more width table.

Comment: The remaning 0.22 is related to margins ?

Comment: The `\tabcolsep` spacing is there too, which is twice `6pt` for each column, unless switched off

Comment: Shouldn't it be `0.88\textwidth`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer indeed the sum gives 0.88

Comment: @SAM To de-confuse you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `tabular` specification such as

```
\begin{tabular}{
  p{0.15\textwidth}
  p{0.12\textwidth}
  p{0.17\textwidth}
  p{0.17\textwidth}
  p{0.27\textwidth}
}
```

means reserving `0.88\textwidth` for the columns. However, each column is surrounded on either side by spaces as wide as the value of `\tabcolsep` (default `6pt`).

If you really need columns with those widths, you can locally set `\tabcolsep`; assuming that the first column has no space on its left and the last column no space at its right, you still have eight spaces to take care of. So we want to divide `0.12\textwidth` equally among eight chunks, and the right width is `0.015\textwidth`; here's an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{showframe,lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[htp]

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.015\textwidth}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}% remove space at the left
  p{0.15\textwidth}
  p{0.12\textwidth}
  p{0.17\textwidth}
  p{0.17\textwidth}
  p{0.27\textwidth}
  @{}% remove space at the right
}
\toprule
aa aa aa aa aa & bb bb bb bb bb & cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc &
  dd dd dd dd dd dd dd dd & ee ee ee ee ee ee ee ee ee ee ee ee \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{A table}

\end{table}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Using `TeX` or `LaTeX` ways to estimate the length of the columns without the additional column space and taking that into account again.

This shows, that `0.88\textwidth` is already too large!

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\dummylength}

\newbox\mybox

\setbox\mybox=\hbox{%
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.15\textwidth}p{0.12\textwidth}*{2}{p{0.17\textwidth}}p{0.27\textwidth}}
    Foo & Foo & Foo & Foo & Foo%
  \end{tabular}%
}%

\def\numofcolumns{5}

\begin{document}

Textwidth is: \the\textwidth

Width of the tabular box: \the\wd\mybox

\setlength{\dummylength}{0.88\textwidth}

\numofcolumns\ columns introduce an additional length of \the\dimexpr\tabcolsep * \numofcolumns*2


0.88 textwidth is \the\dummylength 

Now let's add up the column textwidths again: \the\dimexpr0.17\textwidth*2+0.27\textwidth*2

\setlength{\dummylength}{\dimexpr\dummylength+\tabcolsep*\numofcolumns*2}

Estimated total width:  \the\dummylength

There's a difference of \the\dimexpr\wd\mybox - \dummylength

\noindent\unhbox\mybox%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What puzzles me: Why is there this small (tiny!) difference?

Comment: Why `0.88\textwidth` is too large since `\the\dimexpr\wd\mybox` < `\dummylength` ? is it supposed to be even smaller

Comment: @SAM: The reported box width is smaller than what I expected!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I think that the small discrepancy of -0.00526pt is entirely due to rounding errors within your `\dimexpr`; indeed, adding up the summands in a different way I get 363.59642pt, as expected.  While we are at it: remember to say `\noindent` before `\unhbox\mybox`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: I suspected rounding errors too initially, but then thought: 'hey, it's `\dimexpr`, that should be able to cope with such values' ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The width of your `tabular` environment is `0.88\textwidth` *plus* `10\tabcolsep`. The default value of `\tabcolsep` is `6pt`. If and only if the width of the text block happens to be `500pt` (ca. 6.92" or 17.57cm) will it be the case that the width of this tabular environment equals `\textwidth`. (Why `500pt`? Hint: solve `(1-0.88)*\textwidth=60pt` for `\textwidth`.)

To simplify the setting up of a table whose overall width is equal to `\textwidth` and which has five columns whose proportional widths are 15 : 12 : 17 : 17 : 27, I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment. Note that the *relative* column widths -- as a fraction of the width *if all columns were equally wide* -- may be expressed as `0.852\hsize`, `0.682\hsize`, `0.966\hize` (twice), and `1.534\hsize`, respectively. (Observe that 0.852+0.682+0.966+0.966+1.534=**5**, the number of columns.) Hence, define the `tabularx` environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Z}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ Z{0.852} Z{0.682} *{2}{Z{0.966}} Z{1.534} }
\hline
a & b & c & d & e \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\smallskip
\hrule % just to illustrate the width of the textblock
\end{document}
```