# How do I display this image in a single column, for a 2 column paper one after the other in the centre

Tags: two-column, wide-image, center

[image]

I tried the following

```
\begin{center}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width =11cm, height = 5cm]{confusion-matrix.png}
    \caption{Confusion matrix
    }
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure} 
\end{center}
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: This question may be useful for you. [How to make a figure span on two columns in a scientific paper?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/how-to-make-a-figure-span-on-two-columns-in-a-scientific-paper)

Comment: thanks @Pratyush That really helped.

Comment: @GV-9wj  welcome to the site -- you could have a look at the answer below adapted from  -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333309/how-to-put-several-images-side-by-side-in-just-one-column-in-a-two-column-docume?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
%first three figures
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Level 1}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Level 2}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Level 3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{some caption text}
\end{figure}
%second single figure
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Level 1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{some caption text}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2-7]

\end{document}
```