# Equations on two minipages should be on the same height/use the same height

Tags: equations, align, minipage

I want to create an worksheet with several equations, which are enumerated. To get two columns I separated my page into two minipages. I got the same amount of equations on each minipage, but they don't align horizontally, which I want them to. How can I align my equations horizontally?

EDIT: If someone could tell me how to insert a blank space with the height of an (for example) fraction I would be fine.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Test \\
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\item\vspace{1pt}
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\frac{1}{5}(x^2+x+5)
\intertext{\item\hspace{1pt}}
f(x)&=2x^2(3x+4)
\intertext{\item\hspace{1pt}}
f(x)&=\frac{1}{8}(3x^4-8x^3+16)
\intertext{\item\hspace{1pt}}
f(x)&=12x^{\frac{1}{2}}-4
\intertext{\item\hspace{1pt}}
f(x)&=15x^0
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\item\vspace{1pt}
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=x^{-3}
\intertext{\item\hspace{1pt}}
f(x)&=2-x^{-2}+4x^{-1}
\intertext{\item\hspace{1mm}}
f(x)&=(x-3)^2+4
\intertext{\item\hspace{1pt}}
f(x)&=2(x+15)^2-38
\intertext{\item\hspace{1pt}}
f(x)&=(x^3\cdot x^2)+x^4
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always, an empty line signifies a paragraph break, so you need to remove the one between the minipages, and add a `%` after the first `\end{minipage}` to remove the space caused by the linebreak. And use `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`.

Comment: I inserted the spaces just for better understanding, but okay they are wrong right. But that's not the problem...The % symbol doesn't change anything either...Neither does the `\linewidth`

Comment: The `%` and `\linewidth` only removes the overfull hbox you get. But I see the problem, you're after `\vphantom{\frac{1}{2}}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you didn't have the empty line between your two `minipage`s in your actual code, but if you did, then you would have needed to remove it, as it signifies a paragraph break, which means the minipages will be placed one above the other.

But to answer your actual question, to make sure all the equations have the height of a fraction, you can insert a `\vphantom{1}{2}` in the lines that do not have a fraction.

In addition, with

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
...
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
...
\end{minipage}
```

you will get an overfull hbox warning, because the minipages will be a little bit indented in a list. Using `\linewidth` instead, cf. [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize), takes care of that.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test 

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\item\vspace{1pt}
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\frac{1}{5}(x^2+x+5)
\intertext{\item\hspace{1pt}}
f(x)&=2x^2(3x+4)\vphantom{\frac{1}{5}}
\intertext{\item\hspace{1pt}}
f(x)&=\frac{1}{8}(3x^4-8x^3+16)
\intertext{\item\hspace{1pt}}
f(x)&=12x^{\frac{1}{2}}-4\vphantom{\frac{1}{5}}
\intertext{\item\hspace{1pt}}
f(x)&=15x^0\vphantom{\frac{1}{5}}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\item\vspace{1pt}
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=x^{-3}\vphantom{\frac{1}{5}}
\intertext{\item\hspace{1pt}}
f(x)&=2-x^{-2}+4x^{-1}\vphantom{\frac{1}{5}}
\intertext{\item\hspace{1mm}}
f(x)&=(x-3)^2+4\vphantom{\frac{1}{5}}
\intertext{\item\hspace{1pt}}
f(x)&=2(x+15)^2-38\vphantom{\frac{1}{5}}
\intertext{\item\hspace{1pt}}
f(x)&=(x^3\cdot x^2)+x^4\vphantom{\frac{1}{5}}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain what you want in a much simpler way with the `tasks`package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{counter-format =tsk[1]., label-width=1em, item-indent=0em, before-skip =\medskipamount, after-item-skip=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, before=\everymath{\displaystyle}]
  \item Test
        \begin{tasks}(2)
          \task $ f(x) = \frac{1}{5}(x²+x+5) $

          \task $ f(x) = 2x²(3x+4) $

          \task $ f(x)= \frac{1}{8}(3x⁴-8x³+16) $

          \task $ f(x) = 12x^{\frac{1}{2}}-4 $

          \task $ f(x) = 15x⁰ $

          \task $ f(x) = x⁻³ $

          \task $ f(x) = 2-x⁻²+4x⁻¹ $

          \task $ f(x) = (x-3)²+4 $

          \task $ f(x) =2 (x+15)²-38 $

          \task $ f(x) = (x³ · x²)+x⁴ $
        \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]