# Subfigure widths in two-column layout

Tags: subfloats, two-column, subcaption, width

I want both figures side by side in one column of a two-column LaTeX document, but the result is both the figures are one below another.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{cure.png}
    \caption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill %%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{cluto.png}
    \caption{Picture 2}
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. ( in future)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general `\textwidth` is the total width of the text area, so you shouldn't specify `figure` widths in twocolumn layout in terms of this width (only for `figure*` environments).

If you want the figure to only span one column in a twocolumn document, use `\columnwidth` (see [egreg's answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16956/30280) for the reason why) instead.

So in short:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill %%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Picture 2}
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

This will produce the following:

> [image: Output]