# Why are images indent like paragraphs?

Tags: graphics, indentation, wide-image

[image]

Using [`\textwidth`, `\linewidth` or `\hsize`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16942/50146) has no difference. I don't mind if it indents, but the image should be center-aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/Ooker/Desktop/Images/}}
\title{Quả cầu}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Octahedron}

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
```

I use XeLaTeX.

Comment: Because in this case this is just a (large) text element, and as you show, new paragraphs are indented. If you want to center the image, use for example the `center` environment.

Comment: Just like most other latex constructs (eg minipage or tabular) includegraphics has no positioning code at all, it just makes a box the size of the image, that box is positioned a part of latex's layout just as if was a letter of that size.  So you can use any of the ways that you would use to position `X`  eg `\begin{center} X \end{center}`