# How can I put two images side by side with individual borders in a multi-column environment?

Tags: graphics

I need to put two images within a single column in a two-column page such that each subfigure will have a border around it. I have tried the following:

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
 \tcbox[colback=white] {\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{img1}} 
 \caption{img1}
 \end{subfigure} 
\quad
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
  \tcbox[colback=white]{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth] 
   {img2}} 
  \caption{img2}
 \end{subfigure}
\caption{Comparison of images (a) img1 and (b) img2}

\end{figure}
```

However, I am not able to place the images properly. I want them to be placed side by side and both the images and the text should be center aligned. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? You need to be using `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth` here. So for example, I've changed both your `subfigure` to have a width of `0.4\linewidth`. This way they can both fit in the column. For more reading see [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize/).

To get the `subfigure` center aligned, use `\centering` within the `subfigure`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry} % <--- showframe used just as a visual aid.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt} % <--- to draw a line between the columns, just as an aid to visualise the alignment in this MWE.

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
 \centering
 \tcbox[colback=white] {\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth] {example-image-a}}
 \caption{img1}
 \end{subfigure} 
 %
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
 \centering
  \tcbox[colback=white]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth] {example-image-b}} 
  \caption{img2}
 \end{subfigure}
\caption{Comparison of images (a) img1 and (b) img2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```