# figure* environment of multicolumn documents, full width without margin

Tags: two-column, width, subfig

Which width, instead of `\textwidth` (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16956/1362)), can I use here to avoid getting an "Overfull \hbox" warning? I expect it's the page width minus margins.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, draft]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{center}
        \subfloat %[] if you want labeled subfigures.
        {
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        }
        \subfloat
        {
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        }
    \end{center}
    \caption{Your caption here}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Gives

> Overfull \hbox (13.33331pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 11--16
>
> [][] |

[image: pdflatex output]

Using four subfigures results in "Overfull \hbox (26.66663pt too wide)", by the way.

Comment: Ideally I would find a solution that would let me avoid guessing at using `.24` or `.485`.

Comment: Well, that would depend on the used code (is there a defined separator value or not, did you use `hfill` or not) and at last on the used images and their sizes ... That makes it not easy or propably impossible to find a formula to handle this in an automatic way ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The culprit here is not `\textwidth`, it is your factor `0.5` which results in an total length for both images as `0.5\textwidth`+ separator length + `0.5\textwidth` > `\textwidth`. **That results in your overful box**.

Just play with the factor, use for example `0.485` as shown in the following mwe (I added package `showframe` to visualize typing area and margins):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{showframe} % <============= to visiualize typing area and margins

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \subfloat %[] if you want labeled subfigures.
  {%
    \includegraphics[width=0.485\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  }%
  \subfloat
  {%
    \includegraphics[width=0.485\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  }%
  \caption{Your caption here}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: resulting figure]

BTW: Because you are using environment `figure*` you can use `\textwidth`, because `figure*` spans both columns. If you use `figure` your figure is placed in one column and you should use `\columnwidth`. Please see the expanded mwe

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{showframe} % <============= to visiualize typing area and margins
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \subfloat %[] if you want labeled subfigures.
  {%
    \includegraphics[width=0.485\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  }%
  \subfloat
  {%
    \includegraphics[width=0.485\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  }%
  \caption{Your caption here}
\end{figure*}

\Blindtext

\begin{figure}[!hb]
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}

\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: resulting figures]

Comment: Thanks for this information. At a high level, I want to, say, put four subfigures in a row, so semantically, they should each take up a 1/4 of the width. Yes, there will be three separators, but I would hope to still specify that four of them should fit snuggly, regardless of the separator (and even if the separator width gets redefined).

Comment: @Gus You can try with four times `\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%`