# Formatting Matplotlib figure with subplots for Latex

Tags: floats, formatting, matplotlib

I'm having trouble getting my plot to span the entire `\textwidth`. Here is an equivalent MWE of what I'm getting when I compile.[image]

Matplotlib code: (`set_size` is a function taken from [here](https://jwalton.info/Embed-Publication-Matplotlib-Latex/), but that doesn't really work either)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(28,5))
# fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=set_size(465, subplots=(1,4)))

for i in range (4):
    sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", err_style="bars", ci=68, ax=ax[i], data=fmri)
plt.suptitle("Timepoint vs Signal")
plt.savefig("timepoint_vs_signal.png")
```

Latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}
\usepackage[lined, boxed, ruled, commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{mathtools,array,savesym}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsthm, amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
% these are the packages I need, so I'm including them just in case it's necessary info

\begin{document}
 
\lipsum[1]

% \showthe\textwidth % = ~469pt

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{timepoint_vs_signal.png}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Look at the PNG, there's a lot of whitespace in it. (Unrelated, but I'd recommend using PDF over PNG.) You can crop the image (or run `pdfcrop` on a PDF, if you generate that), but I guess modifying the subplots to fill the entire figure would be better. That, however, is a Python question, so really out of scope for this site.

Comment: You can try adding `fig.tight_layout()` before saving the figure though.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comments. A quick follow up question, in this case, `\textwidth`, `\columnwidth` and `\paperwidth` are all equivalent, right?

Comment: Not \paperwidth, that I think is the full width of the paper, but the two others are the same in a one column document (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16942), equal to the width of the textblock.