# centering item in itemize/enumerate without centering bullet

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, itemize, minipage

I'm trying to center/align right the content of bullets in an `itemize` nested in a p column of a `longtable`. I use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.1\linewidth} p{0.2\linewidth}  p{0.7\linewidth} }
  \# & question & answer \\
  \hline
  \endhead
  127 & what are your names?
  &
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    {\centering blo\par}
  \item bla
  \item
    {\raggedleft blu\par}
  \end{itemize}
\end{longtable}
  
\end{document}
```

However, the resulting list also centers the bullet associated with the first item:

[image]

Is there anyway to prevent it from doing this without the use of a `minipage` environment?

Comment: Please provide an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) (document class is important for example) and maybe a drawing or picture of the desired output to minimize the risk of a misunderstanding.

Comment: Consider the following: [Instead, when we need something centered with respect to a line in a list, we should use \linewidth:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16956/22413)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thank you very much, I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @A.Ellett This doesn't quite work for me. I also want to avoid using the center environment as it adds spurious space and this seems to not work with `\centering`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, using `\parbox` or `\makebox` depending on whether the item contents is multilined or not. I added a pair of vertical rules to visualise better, and set the bullet indent to 0:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.1\linewidth} p{0.2\linewidth} | p{0.7\linewidth}| }
  \# & question & answer \\
  \hline
  \endhead
  127 & what are your names?
  &
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering blo}
  \item bla
  \item
   \makebox[\linewidth][r]{blu}
  \end{itemize}
\end{longtable}
  
\end{document}
```

[image]