# Is it possible to specify a column width in a table that will fill out the page margins?

Tags: tables

For example:

```
\begin{longtable} { |L{2.75cm}|c|c|c|c| }
```

If the centered columns are already fixed width, is there anything I can write (where 2.75cm is written) to make the first column have a width such that the table occupies the full width of the page within its margins?

MWE with xltabular instead of longtable (doesn't compile):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc]
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibfile.bib}
\DeclareMathOperator\grad{grad}
\DeclareMathOperator\prima{'}
\DeclareMathOperator\sen{sen}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{longtable}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\usepackage[spanish]{minitoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-digits=false}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\mathchardef\mhyphen="2D
\usepackage{xltabular}


\title{Tabla 1}
\author{-}
\date{September 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}


\begin{xltabular}{ |X|c|c|c|c| }
    \caption[Datos del tren de aterrizaje de aviones semejantes.]{\label{tren}}
    \endlastfoot
        \hline
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Tren de Aterrizaje}} \\
        \hline
        & Proyecto & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{A319-100}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{\cite{A319APM,JanesA319,A319TC,EurocontrolA319}}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{B737-700}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{\cite{B737APM,JanesB737,B737TC,EurocontrolB737}}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{A220-300}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{\cite{A220APM,JanesA220,A220TC,EurocontrolA220}}\par}} \\
        \hline
        Tipo & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[1cm][c]{Triciclo}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[1cm][c]{retráctil}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[1cm][c]{Triciclo}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[1cm][c]{retráctil}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[1cm][c]{Triciclo}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[1cm][c]{retráctil}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[1cm][c]{Triciclo}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[1cm][c]{retráctil}\par}} \\
        \hline
        Vía\footnote{La vía $T$ del tren de aterrizaje es la distancia entre el centro de las huellas de los trenes principales. Si son más de dos, tomamos los más alejados del plano de simetría del avión.} $T$ (m) & 6.9338 & 7.59 & 5.72 & 6.73 \\
        \hline
        Batalla\footnote{La batalla $B$ del tren de aterrizaje es la distancia longitdinal entre el centro de la huella del tren auxiliar y los centros de las huellas de los trenes principales. Si hay más de dos tomamos los de mayor distancia longitudinal respecto al tren auxiliar.} $B$ (m) & 12.7734 & 11.039 & 12.6 & 14.63 \\
        \hline
        Relación $T/B$ & 0.5428 & 0.6869 & 0.4540 & 0.4600 \\
        \hline
        Relación $T/b$ & 0.1995 & 0.2226 & 0.1667 & $\sim$ 0.2093 \\
        \hline
        Relación $B/{l_f}$ & 0.3653 & 0.3262 & 0.3915 & 0.3781 \\
        \hline
        Número de neumáticos por pata\footnote{Para los datos de las patas del tren de aterrizaje, usamos el subíndice $p$ para referirnos a las patas del tren principal, y el subíndice $a$ para referirnos al tren auxiliar.} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$N_p = 2$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$N_a = 2$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$N_p = 2$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$N_a = 2$}\par}}  & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$N_p = 2$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$N_a = 2$}\par}}  & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$N_p = 2$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$N_a = 2$}\par}}  \\
        \hline
        Denominación del neumático & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3.25cm][c]{Pr: H42x16-19}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3.25cm][c]{Aux: 25.75x6.75-14}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{Pr: 46x16-20}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{Aux: 30x8.8-15}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{Pr: 43.5x16-21}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{Aux: 27x7.7-15}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{Pr: 42x15-21}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{Aux: 27x8.5-12}\par}} \\
        \hline
        Diámetro (m) & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$D_p =  1.0668$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$D_a = 0.6541$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$D_p = 1.1784$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$D_a = 0.762$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$D_p = 1.1049$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$D_a = 0.6858$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$D_p = 1.0668$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$D_a = 0.6858$}\par}} \\
        \hline
        Ancho (m) & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$b_p = 0.4064$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$b_a = 0.1715$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$b_p = 0.4064$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$b_a = 0.2235$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$b_p = 0.4064$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$b_a = 0.1956$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$b_p = 0.381$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$b_a = 0.2159$}\par}} \\
        \hline
        Presión de inflado (MPa) & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$p_p = 1.31$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$p_a = 1.372$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$p_p = 1.19$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$p_a = 1.14$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$p_p =$ 1.36 - 1.41}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$p_a = 1.42$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$p_p = 1.47$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{$p_a = 1$}\par}} \\
        \hline
\end{xltabular}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You wish to combine the functionality of [`longtable`](//ctan.org/pkg/longtable) and [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). This is achieved using [`ltablex`](//ctan.org/pkg/ltablex) and similar packages.

Comment: Use the `xltabular` environment, from the homonymous package, which brings the functionalities (and syntax) of `longtable` to `tabularx`  and replace `{|L|c|c|c|c|}` with `{|X|c|c|c|c|}` .

Comment: @Bernard I tried just that, and got a compile error. I edited the question to provide an MWE.

Comment: You forgot to specify the total width of the table, like this: `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|X|c|c|c|c| }`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. What should I write as textwidth to adjust the table to the margins automatically?

Comment: You load several packages multiple times `siunitx` and `inputenc` for example. The latter of which is not required in up-to-date systems anyways. Loading packages multiple times can also always facilitate errors and option clashes and should be avoided.

Comment: `\textwidth`, as I wrote, if its really between the text margins.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks.

Comment: @Bernard Btw, do you know how to make it so that words don't break in the column when I do this?

Comment: You  can usually use \linewidth.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize?r=SearchResults&s=1|77.1122

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `xltabular` environment takes two required arguments: the intended width, and the set of column specifications. Your code is omitting the first of the two required arguments.

Also, if you don't have `\parindent0pt`, don't forget to insert `\noindent` immediately before `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{...}`.

Comment: Thanks. What should I write as textwidth to adjust the table to the margins automatically?

Comment: @stevederekson555 - How about `\textwidth`?

Comment: Oh right, I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, do you know how to make it so that words don't break in the column when I do this?

Comment: In the table preamble; use `>{\raggedright}X`. But do you really want no hyphenation?