# Prevent a single line at the end of a page

Tags: page-breaking

I have a document with bold single lines before paragraphs, how do I prevent from having these line at the end of the page and the accompanying paragraph at the next page? I wish to have the bold single line together with the paragraph.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Do the answers to the following post help you? [Nopagebreak nopagebreak nopagebreak - why won't LaTeX listen to me?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7230)