# Prevent pagebreak between minted and captionof

Tags: captions, page-breaking, minted

I know there are already many questions there covering that or at least similar topics. I've read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7233/70553) for example but can't get it figured out...

At first here comes my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}% not needed, but not sure if it has any effect

\newcommand{\lstCapLbl}[2]{%
    \vspace{-0.9\baselineskip}
    \captionof{listing}{#1\label{lst:#2}}
    \vspace{0.9\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}
There is some random text here. And some some some some some some some
some some some some some more to get a line full.

\begin{minted}[gobble=1,linenos,tabsize=4,xleftmargin=0.7cm]{js}
    function myFunc(){
        someCode();
        // make it as long as needed to get the page full
        // in my case 35 more lines were needed
        // but they were omitted here for the sake of brevity
    }
\end{minted}
\lstCapLbl{some caption text}{andTheLabel}

And again some random Text just for fun.

\end{document}
```

What you get if you insert the right number of rows looks like that:

[image: what an unwanted pagebreak looks like]

But what I'd like to get is something like that (I just added some more lines for the showcase):

[image: how it should look]

The last lines of the `minted` block should go on the next page! As you probably guess, I don't want to put the code into a `minipage` environment or something since it should span over multiple pages.

What I tried so far is putting `\nopagebreak` at every possible place. It doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
\newcommand{\lstCapLbl}[2]{%
  \nopagebreak
  \vspace{-0.9\baselineskip}
  \nopagebreak
  \captionof{listing}{#1\label{lst:#2}}
  \vspace{0.9\baselineskip}
}
```

I also put it between the `minted` environment and the `\lstCapLbl`. I also tried to play with `widowpenalty` and `clubpenalty` but that didn't help either.

```
\end{minted}
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\lstCapLbl{some caption text}{andTheLabel}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encapsulate the `minted` environment into a breakable `tcolorbox` environment. This allows to use some options from the `tcolorbox` package to influence the breaking.

The minimal effect of the following code is that at least *one* line will be broken to the next page, if any. Since that may be not pleasing enough, I encluded an option

```
enlargepage flexible=3\baselineskip
```

This allows the unbroken page to be enlarged up to 3 lines to fit the listing (that is rather large). But then, a broken listing will always have at least *three* lines on the following page. You can reduce that to

```
enlargepage flexible=2\baselineskip
```

for *two* lines or delete that option, if *one* broken line is enough.

I made a new environment `myminted` which contains all that stuff.

The full code is:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[minted,breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}

\newtcblisting{myminted}[4][]{
  blanker,bottom=0.9\baselineskip,
  breakable,listing only,
  before skip=0.9\baselineskip,
  after skip=0.9\baselineskip,,
  minted options={#1},
  minted language={#2},
  attach boxed title to bottom center,
  minipage boxed title,
  boxed title style={blanker},
  title={{\captionof{listing}{#3\label{lst:#4}}}},
  enlargepage flexible=3\baselineskip% <--- may be reduced to 2\baselineskip or be deleted
}

\begin{document}
There is some random text here. And some some some some some some some
some some some some some more to get a line full.

\begin{myminted}[gobble=1,linenos,tabsize=4,xleftmargin=0.7cm]{js}
  {some caption text}{andTheLabel}
    function myFunc(){
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        someCode();
        // make it as long as needed to get the page full
        // in my case 35 more lines were needed
        // but they were omitted here for the sake of brevity
    }
\end{myminted}


And again some random Text just for fun.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tried it, needed some time to update packages, but it works great, even over several pages!

Since I was on holiday in the final time of the bounty, I unfortunately couldn't award you the bounty. But I read that you get the bounty afterwards if you give the highest voted answer. I could even start a new bounty and award it, I don't know...

Comment: @caligula That automatism did'nt work here, because there was only one click given to my answer at that time. But I'm glad to hear that you appreciate my answer :-)