# Bug in includegraphics

Tags: graphics, pdftex, debugging

I have an image (image.pdf, http://www.solidfiles.com/d/d8874ce2ff/).
This is how the image looks like:[image: original image]

And this small TeX code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{image.pdf}
\end{document}
```

This returns the following output:[image: image processed by latex]

Obviously, there are a few things missing, e.g. b/a and z. Why?

Can anyone reproduce this? I am using TeXShop (Typeset, LaTeX) on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: I think something of this kind has already appeared on the site.

Comment: was there a solution found?

Comment: Yes! `:-)` Add `\pdfinclusioncopyfont=1` at the start of the file; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98353/embedded-fonts-not-showing-up-correctly-in-pdf-generated-using-pdfpages-in-pdfla

Comment: @egreg Ah, I thought it was another one (I linked it in my answer). :D But does that work only using `pdfpages` and not `graphicx`?

Comment: Here's another one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50829/ligatures-in-figures-and-pdftex

Comment: thx!! `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1` worked perfectly! ... it's always hard to find the right wording for a question^^

Answer (score 2):

This has been encountered before, see also: [\includegraphics and \includepdf both remove all copy (text) from my (R outputted) pdf graphs, using pdfTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5573/includegraphics-and-includepdf-both-remove-all-copy-text-from-my-r-outputte)

So as I was suspecting it's a font problem. You can compile your document using XeLaTeX (or XeTeX), not pdflatex.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{image.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The site converts uploaded PDF files to PNG, as far as I know.

Comment: the problem occurs if I use the original image.pdf, which I uploaded on solidfiles (see pls link)

Comment: @Andy Yes, I noticed that. I'm looking into it. :D

Comment: @Andy Edited answer. Although apparently egreg meant another question.